# OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to learn flask-mysql [using this link](http://www.techillumination.in/2014/01/python-web-application-development.html)
but i am getting certain type of error

```
from flask import Flask
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
app = Flask(__name__)

mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASEE_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'EmpData'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return 'hello people'

@app.route("/Authenticate")
def Authenticate():
  username = request.args.get('UserName')
  password = request.args.get('Password')
  cursor = mysql.get_db().cursor()
  cursor.execute("SELECT * from User where Username='" + username + "' and Password='" + password + "'")
  data = cursor.fetchone()
if data is None:
 return "Username or Password is wrong"
else:
 return "Logged in successfully"

if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(debug = True)
```

help me understand this problem
in terminal:
    mysql -u root -p
    ;password: root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here -> `app.config['MYSQL_DATABASEE_PASSWORD'] = 'root'`

Correct the key to `app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'root'` instead, i.e., remove the extra `E` character from `MYSQL_DATABASEE_PASSWORD`.

Comment: It is also possible, that the root password isn't root - looks like it has been copied from the tutorial

Comment: @MaximilianKindshofer could be the case, though OP does mention in the last line again that he is using password `root`.

Comment: @MaximilianKindshofer i mentioned i am using password as root. thanks anyways